# Is there a way to access the text currently being typed in insert mode?

Tags: vimscript, functions, cursor-motions, cursor

From [`:help registers`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#registers) I know that the `.` register contains the last inserted text. However, thanks to the following `autocmd`, I have verified that it's content is actually updated *after* exiting insert mode, and not along the way.

```
augroup Foo
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChangedI *.tex echo strftime('%S') . ': ' . @.
augroup END
```

Is there a way to access that text while I type it?

---

A possible strategy I thought about is to get of the current column on [`InsertEnter`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#InsertEnter) and on [`TextChangedI`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#TextChangedI) via `col('.')`, and use the two to index into `getline('.')`.

But I wanted to know if a solution exists already.

Comment: Indexing only the current line is fallible; you need to index positions in the whole buffer (consider pressing Enter in Insert mode, and what about Backspace with settings that allow deleting non-inserted text?). I’m not aware of any prior solutions here, unfortunately.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thanks. Yeah, the matter is not simple. For now I'm relatively happy with accessing the text from the position I started the insertion onward, if any. The reason for this is that I want to highlight the text I'm typing right now so that I can see if I am writing to often the same words in a given prose-mainly buffer (say a TeX source). Some hint is in [this other question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42059/autocmd-to-set-hls-after-having-manually-nohls-doesnt-turn-search-highlighing?noredirect=1#comment75208_42059).