# autocmd to set hls after having manually :nohls doesn't turn search highlighing on

Tags: search, autocmd, highlight

**tl;dr**

Why, after `source`ing the following, moving the cursor doesn't result in the text matching the `/` being highlighted?

```
set hls
augroup AU_NAME
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved * set hls
augroup END
nohls
```

---

**Original question**

I like to have this mapping

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>hl :nohls<CR>
```

so that I can quickly dismiss the search highlighting, which can be at times confusing for the eyes, when the previous search result is no more of interest.

But at the same time I'm exploring the possibility of filling the search buffer `/` as I write with the text I'm writing, for the purpose of immeditaly spotting, as I type, text repetions when writing prose.

However, I have noticed a behavior I don't understand.

1. Start Vim with `vim -Nu NONE some-file`;
2. `:source` the file below, which sets a few options and an `autocmd` for putting the inserted text in the search buffer when leaving insert mode;

   ```
   set hls
   set incsearch
   augroup AU_NAME
     autocmd!
     autocmd InsertLeave * let @/ = @.
   augroup END
   ```
3. <kbd>i</kbd> and insert some text, e.g. `hello`
4. <kbd>Escape</kbd> and you'll see the inserted text being highlighted
5. `:nohls`
6. <kbd>i</kbd> and insert `world`
7. <kbd>Escape</kbd>, but you will not see world highlighted, because of step 5, according to [`:h :nohls`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%3Anohlsearch)¹
8. `:set hls` turns the highlighting on.

Because of the above, I thought I could add `autocmd InsertLeave * set hls` to the `augroup` and reach the same effect as above,

```
set hls
set incsearch
augroup AU_NAME
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertLeave * let @/ = @.
  autocmd InsertLeave * set hls
augroup END
```

however that doesn't seem to help.

---

(¹) It reads

> is automatically turned back on when using a search command, or setting the 'hlsearch' option

Comment: You should probably investigate `:help matchadd()` instead.

Comment: @romainl, thank you very much. I see that probably `:2match` is what I need, with a custom `{group}`.