# How does <cword> work in insert mode?

Tags: autocmd, insert-mode, cword

Basically I want to access the last `\w\+` in my current insertion. (Hence I asked [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42057/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-text-currently-being-typed-in-insert-mode).)

Another solution I thought of was something like the following (I'm `echo`ing, but clearly I'd pass it to a function in my real usecase¹):

```
augroup Foo
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChangedI,TextChangedP * echo '<' . expand('<cword>') . '>'
augroup END
```

but it doesn't, as it prints `<>` while I type, and it does put some word in between `<` and `>` when I go insert mode, ... but not always. So I think I've not really understood what `<cword>` is and what makes it change.

---

(¹) I have come up with a fairly complex solution, whereby I pass `col('.')` to the function in the `autocmd` (the one taking the palce of the `echo` in the toy example above) and use that to regex-match the last word being written.

Comment: You might try `<C-r><C-w>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<cword>` is mostly a command-line mode thing, not an insert mode thing. I don't think it is reliable in this context.

Here is how I would approach the initial problem:

```
augroup Foo
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChangedI,TextChangedP * echom getline('.')->matchstr('\w\+\%.c')
augroup END
```

where…

- `:help getline()` grabs the text of the given line,
- `:help matchstr()` returns the part of it that matches the given pattern,
- `\w\+\%.c` matches as many word characters as possible (`\w\+`) before the cursor (`\%.c` is a zero-width match).

Issues left for OP to figure out:

- This grabs the word before the cursor, which is not necessarily the word that is being inserted. Leaving a mark on `InsertEnter` and using that to anchor the pattern might help.

Comment: "pettern"… *sigh*.